# Capture rowcount in for loop using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I am writing a stored proc to import data from S3 bucket. S3 bucket have csv files stored in a structure as below:

> S3Bucket/foldername/tablename/file1 -- 10 rows

> S3Bucket/foldername/tablename/file2 -- 20 rows

> S3Bucket/foldername/tablename/file3 -- 20 rows

I am able to perform the import on Amazon RDS (postgres) using pgAdmin by using a for loop against the table which have the foldername in place.But,I need to store the number of records in each file in a log table for which I created a variable __rowcounts int.

```
declare 
__rec record;
__delimiter_value varchar(100);
__import_query varchar(65000);
__start_datetime timestamp;
__end_datetime timestamp;
__tablename varchar(100);
__rowcount int DEFAULT 0;
__filename varchar(100);
__truncate varchar(65000);
__sql varchar(65000);
__s3bucket varchar(200);
__region varchar(100);
__path varchar (10000);
__table varchar(100);
__tblname record;

BEGIN
FOR __rec IN
    (SELECT        
          u.dbname,
          s.tbl_id,
          s.tblname,
          s.tbl_schema,
          u.filename
           FROM public.tbl1 s
            JOIN public.utbl2 u
     ON    s.dbname = u.dbname 
     AND   s.tbl_schema||'.'||s.tblname = u.tblname
     where s.dbname = current_database() 
    )

BEGIN
LOOP
   
    __table:= __rec.tbl_schema||'.'||__rec.tblname;
    __filename := __rec.filename ;
    __delimiter_value :=  '(FORMAT CSV,DELIMITER ''''|'''', QUOTE ''''"'''',  NULL '''''''')';
    __s3bucket := 'bucketname';
    __region := 'regionname';
    __path := _folderpath||'/'||_dbname||'/'||__rec.tblname||'/'||__rec.filename;
    __import_query :=  FORMAT(
                             $query$ SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3('%s', '', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')$query$,
                            __table, __delimiter_value, __s3bucket, __path, __region
);

EXECUTE __import_query;
EXECUTE 'select count(*) from '||__rec.tbl_schema||'.'||__rec.tblname into __rowcount;

INSERT INTO public.logs(tbl_id,
                            dbname,
                            tblname,
                            filename,
                            rowcount)
                        VALUES
                           (__rec.tbl_id,
                            __rec.dbname,
                            __rec.tblname,
                            __filename,
                            __rowcount
                           );

END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;
```

output in logs file is coming up as

| tbl_id | dbname | tblname | filename | rowcounts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | Y | file1 | 10 |
| 1 | X | Y | file2 | 30 |
| 1 | X | Y | file3 | 50 |

Output I am expecting is:

| tbl_id | dbname | tblname | filename | rowcounts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | Y | file1 | 10 |
| 1 | X | Y | file2 | 20 |
| 1 | X | Y | file3 | 20 |

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything in your stored procedure. But can you add a `WHERE` clause in your select count(*) query. Something like WHERE __rec.filename = <current file name>

Comment: @bfris target table doesn't have a __rec.filename column to apply where clause.